# Submitting another ipa file right after previous submission

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

Can I submit another archived iPA file while previous version have been just submitted and waiting for review in iTunes Connect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure you can, you will just need to bump the build number so that the new upload is displayed in the list of available builds which you then choose to submit. I don't think iTunes connect supports overwriting binary files on upload.

Comment: Will I wait more for my app being reviewed in this case?

Comment: I guess so, yes. You asked about submitting "right after previous submission", so its not that much more of a wait?

Comment: Well, sorry i meant  after 2 days for ex.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can upload newer ipa even after submition for review
Check out the link for detailed information 
[App review status](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/Chapters/ChangingAppStatus.html)